# How to change only one value in the Gson object Stored in the Shared Preferrence

Tags: java, android, json, android-sharedpreferences, gson

This is the `JSON`

[image]

I am saving this `JSON` in `shared preference` using this function

```
public static void persistUser(Context context, User user) {
    mUser = user;
    SharedPreferences.Editor pref = 
    context.getSharedPreferences(USER_SHAREDS, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    pref.putString(USER_DATA, new Gson().toJson(user, User.class));
    pref.apply();
 }
```

Now I want to change value in user_data -> user cover image without change all the other data 
**only just need to change only any one value in without change other things**

help me to solve this in simple way ??

Comment: I can see no other way: just read your object from SharedPreferences, make a Gson object in which you can update the field then store it back using the method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can get user out and save it back after your changes by call function.

```
//Get user
User user = getPersistUser(context);

//Change
user.setCoverImage(true)

//Save
persistUser(context, user)
```

Get user function like

```
public static CoreUser getCoreUserInfo(Context context) {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = CacheHelper.read(context, CoreUser.OBJECT_NAME, "");
     return gson.fromJson(json, CoreUser.class);
}
```

Comment: User user = getPersistUser(context);

//Change
user.setCoverImage(true)

//Save
persistUser(context, user)

this thing solve my problem